# Creating javascript function on server side with string.format, best way and alternatives

Tags: c#, javascript, string.format

on one of the project I was delegated to I saw some c# code like this

```
string.format("some JavaScript function(){{ {0}.setValue and do magic",param1,param2,...");
```

Then the function was set as index changed method of some JavaScript element.

It's not the first time I saw it but its the first time it struck me so hard. The actual code was enormous and there was large number of parameters passed.

I was wondering if there is a better way (Probably plenty?) cause this seemed for me like a poor one. Writing complex javascript logic can be painful and writing it using string.format is semi insane for me. Can some 1 explain to me what are the alternatives and best practices are?

Thanks for help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not some *really* need of generating conditional `javascript` code for the client, bacause that is what the presented code is doing, I would strongly advice to keep JS on client, and deliver it to the client via different standard mechanisms available in browser.

In short

- use client side `JS` delivered via `JS` files or like a text and after treated like `JS`, but this is often for advanced scenarious.
- use any MVC framework on *client side*, to avoid continue callback to the server, if you don't really need it, and manage states and appearance of content on your site in easier way.

  a) [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)

  b) [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)

  ... many others...